# Creating / Calculating a new grouped Variable in R

Tags: r

Here is how my dataset looks like:

```
cpus rows time
1     500   3
1     1000  10
1     2000  40
4     500   2
4     1000  6
8     500   1
8     1000  3
8     2000  10
8     3000  30
```

and I want to create a new variable speedup which is calculated:

time(for **one** cpu) / time (for **n** cpus) for each amount of rows

So, I should end up with something like this:

```
cpus rows time speedup
1     500   3    1
1     1000  10   1
1     2000  40   1
4     500   2    1.5
4     1000  6    1,67
8     500   1    3
8     1000  3    3.33
8     2000  10   4
8     3000  30   NA
```

I already tried to do that with `aggregate()`, `summaryBy()` and `ddply()` - but I could not figure out how to calculate something else than e.g. a mean with them, though i think there might be a solution with a least one of these.

How do I do this in R?

Clarification: I already edited my dataset example to make one point more clear, there are some missing cases like e.g. there might be no case for one cpu and 3000 rows, but the times for one cpu are always the reference for the calculation of the speedup variable and must be always connected to the rows variable. So, if this case (one cpu, 3000 rows) is missing, you cannot calculate the speedup for 8 cpus, 3000 rows.

Comment: your question is not clear to me, however, if you need to have the cpu time, you can use ?system.time

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
mapply(FUN = '/' , df$time[df$cpus==1 ], df$time) # df your data.frame
# [1] 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.500000 1.666667 1.600000 3.000000 3.333333 4.000000
# or simply
df$time[df$cpus==1 ]/df$time
```

And if you want to write it as a fraction, you can use the **fractions** from the package **MASS**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(speedup = time[cpus == 1] / time)
```

You would get:

```
#  cpus rows time  speedup
#1    1  500    3 1.000000
#2    1 1000   10 1.000000
#3    1 2000   40 1.000000
#4    4  500    2 1.500000
#5    4 1000    6 1.666667
#6    4 2000   25 1.600000
#7    8  500    1 3.000000
#8    8 1000    3 3.333333
#9    8 2000   10 4.000000
```

Or a quick and dirty way to get your desired output:

```
df %>% mutate(speedup = ifelse(time[cpus == 1]/time == 1, 1, 
                               paste0(time[cpus == 1], "/", time)))
```

You would get:

```
#  cpus rows time speedup
#1    1  500    3       1
#2    1 1000   10       1
#3    1 2000   40       1
#4    4  500    2     3/2
#5    4 1000    6    10/6
#6    4 2000   25   40/25
#7    8  500    1     3/1
#8    8 1000    3    10/3
#9    8 2000   10   40/10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess, i missed to mention something important. The data is not so coherent, that there is a time value for every cpu & row combination. So there might be some missing values like the way i edited my question post!

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing your question please ? It is really unclear.